# Can I force flush a Databricks Delta table, so the disk copy has latest/consistent data?

Tags: azure-data-factory, databricks, delta-lake

I am accessing Databricks Delta tables from Azure Data Factory, which does not have a native connector to Databricks tables. So, as a workaround, I create the tables with the LOCATION keyword to store them in Azure Data Lake. Then, since I know the table file location, I just read the underlying Parquet files from Data Factory. This works fine.

But... what if there is cached information in the Delta transaction log that has not yet been written to disk? Say, an application updated a row in the table, and the disk does not yet reflect this fact. Then my read from Data Factory will be wrong.

So, two questions...

- Could this happen? Are changes held in the log for a while before being written out?
- Can I force a transaction log flush, so I know the disk copy is updated?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Data Factory has built in delta lake support (this was not the case at the time the question was raised).

Delta is  available as an inline dataset in a Azure Data Factory data flow activity. To get column metadata, click the Import schema button in the Projection tab. This will allow you to reference the column names and data types specified by the corpus (see also the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-delta)).

Comment: Interesting idea about vacuum() but I agree it looks like a *very* kludgy and risky solution. 

I know the question has been asked before, but there was never a good answer. The ADF feature to invoke Databricks code is different.

Answer (score 0):

ADF supports Delta Lake format as of July 2020:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-factory/adf-adds-connectors-for-delta-lake-and-excel/ba-p/1515793

> The Microsoft Azure Data Factory team is enabling .. and a data flow connector for data transformation using Delta Lake

Delta is currently available in ADF as a public preview in data flows as an [inline dataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-source#inline-datasets).